# How to play/pause sound when button is pressed

Tags: swiftui, avaudioplayer, playsound

I need to play sound (it's in Assets) when I press the button. I got error: "Audio file could not be found"
I got this class:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

  @Published var isPlaying = false

  init() {
      if let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thesound", ofType: "mp3") {
      do {
        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
      } catch {
        print("AVAudioPlayer could not be instantiated.")
      }
    } else {
      print("Audio file could not be found.")
    }
  }

  func playOrPause() {
    guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

    if player.isPlaying {
      player.pause()
      isPlaying = false
    } else {
      player.play()
      isPlaying = true
    }
  }
    
    
}
```

The I got this Button in ContentView:

```
Button(action: {
            audioPlayerViewModel.playOrPause()
          }) {
            Image(audioPlayerViewModel.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFit()
              .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
              .foregroundColor(.white)
```

Thank you!

I tried adding  `inDirectory: "Assets"` into  `if let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thesound", ofType: "mp3", inDirectory: "Assets")` but it didn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is in the asset catalog it's invisible in the application bundle.
Audio files are data assets, you have to access it with [`NSDataAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1913/_index.html)

Replace

```
if let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thesound", ofType: "mp3") {
    do {
      self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
    } catch {
      print("AVAudioPlayer could not be instantiated.")
    }
} else {
    print("Audio file could not be found.")
}
```

with

```
if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "thesound") {
    do {
       self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: asset.data, fileTypeHint: "mp3")
    } catch {
       print("AVAudioPlayer could not be instantiated.", error)
    }
} else {
    print("Audio file could not be found.")
}
```

Note: The argument of `NSDataAsset(name` must be the name of the asset, not the name of the audio file.

Comment: Omg I would got it in milion years. Thanks a lot. It helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "thesound", withExtension: "mp3")
```

Comment: Thanks. This created red alert (Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String') so I changed next line to: self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound) but still doesn't play sound and can't find file.